# Create a template of recurring cards in Trello that are copied, not moved

Tags: trello, trello-cards

Is it possible to create a list in Trello that you can use as a palette or template of recurring task cards?

I am using Trello in a GTD type of way and would like to just drag a recurring task like "Do Expenses" from the palette list and it not be *moved* but copied instead.

Answer (score 3):

Zapier can sort of do this with https://zapier.com/z/60m/zapbook/schedule/trello/9149/create-trello-card-every-month/, while you won't be able "copy a card" on a schedule, you will be able to customize it in the Zapier interface.

[image: schedule trello card creation]

You can of course modify the card however you like, inserting special variables like current month, day of week or time, but you can also add lots of other options like labels and such.

*Disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of Zapier but use Trello a lot personally (it rocks!).*

Comment: FYI I believe Zapier now includes features that allow you to copy a specific cord on a recurring basis.

Answer (score 2):

Trello doesn't currently have any templating features, and there isn't currently a way to copy cards.

We may add that sort of feature in the future, there are currently proposals for [board templates](https://trello.com/card/board/templates-for-boards/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e6fdc349d5bce0000004fa6) and [reusable checklists](https://trello.com/card/board/make-checklists-re-usable/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/4e1e0ab1802ec6e81c0ee19c))

Comment: Please allow a 'duplicate' card or some kind of template.

Answer (score 1):

While this may not be exactly what you are after, this is what I did.

I set up all the recurring tasks in google calendar, with the start date when I wanted the card to come into my inbox.

Feel free to use one I created earlier. With Zapier you can create a free account which would suffice.

http://zpr.io/Th5

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation with the above mentioned service, otherwise your answer will be considered spam and treated accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script that does something similar—you create a card on a specific list, and it updates the card based on the template for the list. All you need is a Google account.

You can find it here: http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/add-enhanced-workflow-to-trello/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into [Echo For Trello](https://echofortrello.com/).  It's an easy way to schedule the re-orcurring creation of cards similar to this.

Trello is now integrated with [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/trello), as well, which could be another way to perform the same task.

Answer (score 0):

To do this manually: Click the three dots at the top-right of a list, and click 'Copy List'.  This will copy the list and all it's cards.  Then you can move the copied list anywhere you like.

To have automatically recurring cards, you can use [Trello's email-to-card](http://help.trello.com/article/809-creating-cards-by-email) feature in conjunction with the freemium service FollowUpThen.

Compose an email with a Trello board's email in the 'to' field, and cc a recurring FollowUpThen email address. Here are [some examples](https://www.followupthen.com/how#formats_recurring):

- 6pmDaily@followupthen.com
- weekdays9am@followupthen.com
- everywed@followupthen.com
- LastFridayOfMonth@followupthen.com
- everyMarch30th11am@followupthen.com
- every3months@followupthen.com

Send the email, and you're all set. The card will be created in Trello at the interval specified in the FollowUpThen email address.